# Decoding Protobuf encoded data using non-supported platform

Tags: protocol-buffers

I am new to Protobufs; I haven't had much exposure to them.  One of the API endpoints we require data from, uses Protobuf encoded data.  This generally wouldn't be an issue if I was using a 'supported' language such as JavaScript, Java, Python or even R to decode the data...

Unfortunately, I am trying to automate the process using Alteryx.  Rather than this being an Alteryx specific question, I have a few questions about Protobufs themselves so I understand this situation better.  I've read through the implementation of Protobufs in Java and Python, and have a basic understanding of how to use them.

To surmise (please correct me if I am wrong), a Protobuf is a method of serializing structured data where a .proto schema is used to encode / decode data into raw binary.  My confusion lies with the compiler.  Google documentation and examples for Python / Java show how a Protobuf compiler (library) is required in order to run the encoding and decoding process. Reading the Google website, it advises that the Protobufs are 'language neutral and platform neutral', but I can't see how that is possible if you need the compiler (and .proto file!) to do the decoding.  For example, how would anyone using a language outside of the languages where Google have a compiler created possibly decode Protobuf encoded data?  Am I missing something?

I figure I'm missing something, since it seems weird that a public API would force this constraint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"language/platform neutral" here simply means that you can reliably get the same data back from any language/framework/platform. The serialization format is defined independently and does not rely on the nuances of any particular framework.

This might seem a low bar, but you'd be surprised how many serialization formats fail to clear it.

Because the format is specified, anyone can create a tool for some other platform. It is a little fiddly if you're not used to dealing in bits, but: totally doable. The protobuf landscape is not dependent on Google - here's a list of some of the known non-Google tools: https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/docs/third_party.md

Also, note that technically you don't even need a .proto; you just need some mechanism for specifying which fields map to which field numbers (since protobuf doesn't include the names). Quite a few in that list can work *either* from a .proto, or from the field/number map being specified *in some other way*. The advantage of .proto is simply that it is *easy* to convey as the schema - and again: isn't tied to any particular language. You can write plugins for "protoc" to add your own tooling, so you don't need to write your own parser from scratch. Or you can write your own parser from scratch if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks Marc for your reply. You've made it much easier to understand - so realistically, we could name the fields within the decoded data whatever we like and use it however we like - the .proto simply provides a suggested (and official) way of naming the variables within the decoded data.

Although I understand the situation better, it still doesn't offer me much help in using .proto files within Alteryx.  Thanks again Marc.

Answer (score 0):

You can't speak of non-supported platform in this case: it is more about languages for which you can't find a protobuf implementation.

My 2 cents is: if you can't find a protobuf implementation for your language, find another language you're familiar with (and popular in protobuf community) and handle the protobuf serialization/deserialization with it. Then call it via a REST API, a executable ... whatever

Comment: I think this is pretty much the way I'm forced to go.  The Alteryx platform allows custom R / Python / Java / JavaScript code, so I'll pick one and do the serialisation / de-serialisation from there.  Thanks.